# azure cosmosDb "mongorestore" failes with "Request size is too large"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, mongorestore, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I try to migrate my mongoDb to azure´s cosmosdb. when I try to do the import as following

```
mongorestore --host $host:10255 -u $user -p $password --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --batchSize 240 --drop --db chronas-api $folderPath
```

I get this error:

> error: Message: {"Errors":["Request size is too large"]}

I have tried already some other values for the --batchSize param but nothing worked.

can someone help me to workaround this issue?

Comment: Do you have documents bigger than 2MB?

Comment: @NickChapsas Is there a workaround for bigger than 2MB collections?

Comment: The limit is not about the collection but the individual document

Comment: I have a document bigger than 2mb. so that means its not possible and I can not use cosmosdb?

Answer (score 1):

> I have tried already some other values for the --batchSize param but
>   nothing worked.

Since you have already tired to try to reduce the number of import documents each batch, I think you need to make sure that per document is less than `2MB`. The maximum size for a document is `2MB` based on the official [statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#documents).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I have a document bigger than 2mb. so that means its not possible and I can not use cosmosdb?

Comment: @aumanjoa Unfortunately, the limitation can not be bypassed so far.

Comment: @aumanjoa If you adopt the answer, you could mark it for others' reference on the forum.Thx.

Comment: @aumanjoa You can, of course, break it up and then use some background job to process them.